# How to use second volume devide of amazon EC2

Tags: debian, amazon-ec2

I have two volumes of amazon EC2 where by default 1 GiB volume using which has fulled.
Now I want to use my second volume which is 9 Gim.
I used command `cat /proc/partitions`
I got `major minor  #blocks  name`

`202        1    1048576 xvda1`

`202       80    9437184 xvdf`
Then I hit `mkfs.ext3 -F /dev/sdf`
its showing

`mkfs.ext3: No such file or directory while trying to determine filesystem size`

then I hit command `df`
and I got

`Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on`

`/dev/xvda1             1032088   1031280         0 100% /`

`tmpfs                   313160         8    313152   1% /lib/init/rw`

`udev                    297800        24    297776   1% /dev`

`tmpfs                   313160         4    313156   1% /dev/shm`

`overflow                  1024        32       992   4% /tmp`

means still I am unable to use my 9 GiB space Volume.

---

I am conform I have two volume where attachment information is 
`i-7e4fb41c:/dev/sda1 (attached)` and `i-7e4fb41c:/dev/sdf (attached)`

where only sda1 is using.
Any one know how may I use my second volume(sdf). Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try using /dev/xvdf . But if I were you I would make partitions on it before making filesystem.

Comment: its working but I think still I am unable to use secondary volume.

Comment: I am getting "E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem." for every command.

like "apt-get install devscripts", "apt-get update", "apt-get upgrade"

Comment: I think still I am unable to use my secondary volume because I am getting - "dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to flush /var/lib/dpkg/updates/tmp.i after padding: No space left on device"

when I am using command  "dpkg --configure -a"

Comment: The second volume's space don't adds to the first. It's a separate disk. You have to mount it somewhere and migrate your data to it.

Comment: how can I do this? can you give me some idea to migrate this.

Comment: It's not so easy, google for "how to grow ami disk".

Answer (score 0):

you should mount `dev/xvdf` instead of `dev/sdf` (because new AMI have upgrade your EBS name to `xvdf`), then you can handle it.